# Plagiarism detection with Search API for Millions of text items

Tags: google-app-engine

I am working on an app that needs plagiarism detection. I am wondering if the new Search API or any other API in app engine (like prospective search) can be used in any way to do this task over millions of entities ?

If not, what is the proposed python library to do that ?

Specifically i need to detect similarity between solutions submitted to course homeworks. They could be programs or even texts but usually would not exceed a few paragraphs each.

I am aware of Winnowing algorithm (sequential hashing), but here the problem is to search millions of submissions for homeworks (not a few).

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are you trying to do exactly? My initial answer to your question was "Yes, the search API can be used to detect plagiarism". But this doesn't tell you the **how** ;)

Comment: @Gnosophilon I just updated the question with more details ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Fulltext Search API to search a corpus of documents; this is subject to the usual caveats of fulltext search: you can search on individual terms and on exact phrases, but there's no 'fuzziness' built in - near matches won't be returned (barring things like stemming, which treat 'phrase' and 'phrased' and 'phrases' as the same word).

Of course, plagiarism detection is a lot more complicated than just finding candidate documents. Your best option may be to use something like TF-IDF to find the most significant words in an input text, use the Fulltext search API to find a set of candidate documents containing those words, and then do a side-by-side comparison in memory on the candidates.